# Select all rows grouped by NULLABLE column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table '**localization_string**' to hold strings for localization of apps. It's used to hold strings for multiple apps ("provider"). Strings have a context (where they are shown). Some string have a numeric provider id, some have a provider id of NULL (these are "default" strings). Some contexts are specified with multiple providers (in separate rows).

I would like to get all strings for a specific provider. This includes all "default" strings but when a context is also specified with the providers id, then this string must be selected.

I have this simplified table structure to serve as illustration:

- context, varchar, not null
- provider_id, number, null

A few simplified example rows could look like this:

```
id   context                | provider_id
----------------------------+------------
1    common.contract.header | NULL    
2    common.contact.address | NULL
3    webcalc.home.title     | NULL
4    webcalc.home.title     | 1
5    webcalc.home.title     | 2
```

So for provider 1 I would like to get string ids 1,2,4. Not #3 because provider_id 1 is specified with the same context and not #2 because it's different than #1.

--- EDIT ---

This is the CREATE TABLE command for 'localization_string':

```
CREATE TABLE `localization_string` (
  `localization_string_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `context` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `entity_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `entity_version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `locale` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `provider` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`localization_string_id`),
  KEY `fk_19cf27dcf987735b3f92dcbe7e2` (`locale`),
  KEY `fk_2b9de3a0dacbfae475f526c12d0` (`provider`),
  KEY `ind_be3921786d4fef28d84f42c24a2` (`context`,`locale`,`provider`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_19cf27dcf987735b3f92dcbe7e2` FOREIGN KEY (`locale`) REFERENCES `locale` (`locale_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_2b9de3a0dacbfae475f526c12d0` FOREIGN KEY (`provider`) REFERENCES `contract_provider` (`contract_provider_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Your help is greatly appreciated, as I can't get my head around this.

Comment: Please give a clear example; sample data and expected result. Your question is not clear.

Comment: What queries have you tried, can you show both example input data and example output data?

Comment: Do you want to return all fields of your table? Also, does your table have a primary key?

Comment: Yes all fields. PK is `id` column.

Comment: Tip: When asking for SQL query help, run `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` and include its output in your question. Don't make us guess at the table and columns, or indexes you may have.

Comment: You updated the question to show the fields that you have, and demonstrated that they're not the ones listed in your example.  Please provided concrete examples of what your input data would be and concrete examples of the results you would want.  Being vague and in-attentive to details won't help us *or* you.

Comment: Your example data still has the fields `id`, `context`, `provider_id`, but your `CREATE TABLE` has no field `id` *(and `provider_id` should have been `provider`)*.

Comment: If you want help, give proper information.  Giving examples which columns don't exist in the table definition won't help you at all.  Also what have you tried so far????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I understand better what you're trying to do.

Here's a solution:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(p.localization_string_id, d.localization_string_id) AS localization_string_id,
  d.context
FROM localization_string AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN localization_string AS p
 ON d.context = p.context AND p.provider = ?
WHERE d.provider IS NULL;
```

The table reference `d` is for the default strings, I assume there's always going to be one default entry for each context.

The table reference `p` is for the optional string for the given provider. The condition on `p.provider=?` must go in the join condition, not the WHERE clause. If there's no row for a given context for that provider, the outer join will return all NULLs.

Then the COALESCE() function returns either the specific row for `p` if there is a match. If not, it'll default to the default row from `d`.

Comment: I cant use MAX because I need to specify a exact provider id (or none).

Comment: @olefrank - That makes no sense.  `MAX()` ***is*** providing you with the exact `provider_id`.  `MAX()` of `NULL` and `1` is `1`...  When would it *not* give you an exact `provider_id`?  *(Have you actually tested this??)*

Comment: MatBaillie: 2 is greater than 1 and NULL! But I want 1!

Comment: @olefrank - You don't have a 2 in the `provider_id` column.

Comment: Matbaillie: Please stop yourself and take a look at the data type on the provider column. That will help you understand my point.

Comment: @olefrank Maybe you should read your own question.  You have a `provider_id` column with the values `NULL`, `NULL`, `1` *(No 2's, in **your own example**.)*.  You also have an `id` column, but that's not in your table definition.  Perhaps fix your own question before putting expletives and criticisms.

Comment: MatBaillie I realize my question was confusing and badly formulated. So I tried to rewrite it to be more clear what I want.

Comment: @olefrank I've rewritten my answer again, take a look.

Comment: Thanks Bill :) This is better than my solution below, I think.

Answer (score 0):

So I've had situations similar to this.  I have yet to find a way other than writing some kind of script or having the query go out and look at the table to see if there's one with a non-null provider_id.  Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM test_tbl t
WHERE 1 = (CASE
           WHEN provider_id IS NULL AND (SELECT 'Y'
                                         FROM test_tbl x
                                         WHERE x.context=t.context
                                         AND x.app=t.app
                                         AND x.provider IS NOT NULL) = 'Y'
              THEN 0
            ELSE 1)
group by app, context, provider_id;
```

I group_by'ed because I didn't know if there might be multiple rows with 'null' or '1'.  Not sure if this will work exactly since I can't test it, but something similar maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution:

```
SELECT 
    cp.context,
    cp.value
FROM
(
SELECT context, value
FROM localization_string
WHERE context LIKE 'common.%' 
    OR (context LIKE 'webcalc-v2.%' AND provider = 1)
) AS cp
INNER JOIN localization_string l
    ON cp.context = l.context
WHERE (l.context LIKE 'common.%' OR l.context LIKE 'webcalc-v2.%')
AND provider IS NULL
```

More optimized solutions with explanations are welcome...